# How do I register a php dll with windows if it's 64 bit windows but 32 bit php and apache?

Tags: php, windows

I have tried running from the command line:

```
regsvr32 libssh2.dll
```

In the syswow64 directory, but it tells me:

```
Loaded but entry point not found. Make sure it's a valid DLL file.
```

Please help, I've been trying for so long :(

This is windows server 2008 64 bit, with php and apache 32 bit.

Comment: are you running `cmd` as an administrator?

Comment: ... but why have 32bit apps and 64bit extensions? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Then libssh2.dll is not a COM server so cannot be registered

Comment: plus1 that's the problem: I missed that